# Error merging multiple data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, merge

I've been trying to merge a list of dataframes and keep getting the error:

> "Error in `[.data.frame`(y, ids$y, y.cols, drop = FALSE) :
> undefined columns selected".

Below is the code I've used

```
 read_OO <- function(filename){
   read.delim(filename, skip=14)
   }# Skip first 14 lines of metadata in data files

filenames <- list.files(folderpath, pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
filelist <- lapply(filenames, read_OO)
SampleIDs <- stringr::str_remove(str_remove(filenames, folderpath), ".txt")
names(filelist) <- SampleIDs
filelist <- mapply(cbind, filelist, SampleIDs, SIMPLIFY=F)
colnames <- c("Wavelength","Absorbance", "SampleIDs")
filelist <- lapply(filelist, setNames, colnames)


abs2017 <- plyr::join_all(filelist, by = c("Wavelength","Absorbance", "SampleIDs"), type = "full", match = "all")
```

The error comes on the last line

I've also tried merging by

```
t <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y,
                            by=c("Wavelength","Absorbance", "SampleIDs"),
                            all = TRUE), filelist)
```

But it stops the code at an "approximate location" (it doesn't provide a specific error and says it can't find the source)

Is there something I can look for in my file structure that may be the problem? I can't find any inconsistencies between the files (they're all identical outputs from a machine)

Answer (score 0):

There was in fact a single file with a slightly different format than all the other files, so this is now solved. Once that was corrected, the code above worked.

If anyone has any comments on how to scan through a list and check for structure discrepancies that would be appreciated!

Comment: What was the format difference?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).